# rail line vs railway line

Tags: word-meaning

What's the difference between "**railway line**" and "**rail line**"? They both seem to mean **a route of rails** to me. Also, I've read somewhere that even "**railway**" standing alone can mean the same thing. Could you clear this up for me, please?

Answer (score 2):

To me, as a British English speaker, **rail line** is not idiomatic - it seems that it is used in American and Australian English. **Railway line** can mean either the tracks or the route of a railway.

> Don't walk on the railway line.
>
> The railway line between A and B passes through C.

**Railway** can refer to a particular company or rail system (**Great Western Railway**) or to an individual route.

Comment: 'Rail line' is pretty common in the UK media.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - [These results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rail+line&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) seemed to me to be mostly US and Australian.

Comment: _Intriguingly, the whole of the figure can be seen clearly only from the air; there is an incomplete view of it_ [the Uffington White Horse] _from nearby villages and the London-to-Bristol rail line. Some think it is a religious figure, others that it functioned as a tribal boundary._ (The Guardian 22 May 2009). Take it from a dyed-in-the wool rail[way] enthusiast. The then nationalised British Railways changed their brand to 'British Rail' in 1965 to seem more 'modern'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Individual citations like that don't tell us much. You need [usage charts like this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=railway+line+to+New+York%2Crailway+line+to+London%2Crailway+to+New+York%2Crailway+to+London&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) (comparing ***railway** [line]* to London / New York) and [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=railroad+line+to+New+York%2Crailroad+line+to+London%2Crailroad+to+New+York%2Crailroad+to+London&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (ditto for ***railroad***).

Comment: If I lived near a route of rails, no matter what route it were because I just wanted to talk about how trains went past my house every day, what would I say? _I live near a/the railway/rails/railway line._

Comment: Well, I would say _I live near a railway line_, but maybe @MichaelHarvey wouldn't! (Incidentally, I heard a BBC newsreader say _rail line_ last night!

Comment: @KateBunting - I would definitely say that _I live near a railway line_, and always have done, but I am aware that not everyone does. Some people even say 'train line' which _really_ bugs me! Saying 'train station' is another thing that some people don't like.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - 'Train station' always sounds to me like something said by a small child who hasn't yet learned the proper expression - but I know some people regard it as perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1):

'Rail line' is more modern and less formal than 'railway line'. They both mean the same thing, a 'route of rails' on which trains can run. 'Railway' can also mean the same thing, and also can be used to refer to the organisation (company, government department, etc) that runs the trains.

Note that 'railway' is more common in British English, and 'railroad' more common in American English.